# First order IVP with unknown continuous function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solving $y''+4y=g(t)$, $y(0)=3$, $y'(0)=-1$ using Laplace Transforms.

I get $Y(s)=\frac{G(s)}{s^{2}+4}+\frac{3s}{s^{2}+4}-\frac{1}{s^2+4}$

Then using Inverse Laplace Transforms, I am not sure of my result: I consider $\frac{G(s)}{s^{2}+4}$ as the Laplace Transform of the convolution $g(t)$ and $f(t)=sin(2t)$ which gives me:

$y(t)=\frac{1}{2} (sin(2t)\ast g(t))+3cos(2t)-\frac{1}{2}sin(2t)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^t sin(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau +3cos(2t)-\frac{1}{2}sin(2t)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^t g(\tau)sin(2t-\tau)d\tau +3cos(2t)-\frac{1}{2}sin(2t)$

Since the convolution is commutative, I write the last equality twice, is this the way to commute the convolution? Also, is this the solution of the IVP?

Comment: Just checking this with Green's functions, I got your answer except it should be $\sin(2t-\color{red}{2}{\tau})$ inside the convolution integral. Confirmed by differentiation. Haven't had time to find where your mistake was. **EDIT**: OK, I think it's obvious. Hopefully you can see it too.

Comment: @user5713492, Thanks! I guess I have to multiply the whole inside of $sin$ by 2 not just the $t$.